# Projects with common user base

Tags: symfony4

how to create a common user base between multiple symfony web sites?
because we can not connect the entities of a project X to a user who is on another database!

project1 
-> user from common db_user
-> entities from db_project1 and linked to common user

project2
-> user from common db_user
-> entities from db_project2 and linked to common user

Comment: Hello there and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide us some more details and show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Simpliest solution is to create a bundle and import it via composer. Much sophisticated could be deploying a service that manages the users and communicating to it with some communication protocol (http, amqp, etc...)

Comment: with a webservice how do I connect my objects with the return of the webservice?